# How to keep the correct line numbering when using ConTeXt vim module?

Tags: context, verbatim

Consider the following code:

```
\usemodule[vim]

\definevimtyping
  [somecode]
  [numbering=yes,lines=split]

\starttext
\startsomecode
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
\stopsomecode
\stoptext
```

It is obvious that the code line (which is of course not actual code) is rather long, but it is one line. In the output one will see:

[image: vim typing]

Note that line numbers have been introduced that do not reflect the line numbers in source. Is it possible to get the "original" line numbering in the output?

*Bonus:* If there is an option, does anyone know of a way to indent text after a line wrap?

Comment: If there is no option with the vim module, but with another ConTeXt module that allow syntax highlighting, I would appreciate an answer showing that.

Comment: Maybe this plugin is using a `set texwdith` .vimrc option by default. Did you try using a .vimrc that would turn off line breaks?

Comment: @sztruks Not yet (I am using vim by opening, editing and saving files and have never looked into the configuration, so I do not know about these parameters).

Comment: “`numbering=yes,lines=split`” What did you expect?

Comment: @HenriMenke Coming from a LaTeX package background concerning listings, I would expect it to break lines in ouput as minted (and listings?) does, but keep the correct line numbering.

Comment: Leaving linebreaking of code to TeX is a bad idea.  Depending on the language the broken lines may actually result in broken code.  Better break manually.  Which language are you targetting?

Comment: @HenriMenke C and Java, but really I would accept "broken" code as long as it is displayed nicely, in the way e.g. minted is able to do it (I do attach the source files, so there is no need for anyone to copy the code).

Comment: @TeXnician I'd suggest you use a code formatter, like [`clang-format`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) and set the linewidth to 80 chars (or whatever fits on the page).

Comment: At the .vimrc level, the `set wrap` may be an option. It does not change the text, but the way it is displayed in the buffer, so line numbering will be the one you expect. It is btw enabled by default in .vim, so this might do the job.

Comment: @sztruks I have just tried your suggestions using `set textwidth` and `set wrap` and haven't got it working.

Comment: I wasn’t clear enough. `set textwidth` is not what you want, because it will break the line. Try `set wrap` alone.

Comment: @sztruks I have tried and it did not work (my comment wasn't clear either).

Answer (score 2):

This is too long to be a comment so I am posting this as an answer. I am the current maintainer of `t-vim` and the one who added the functionality for line numbering. In principle, this is possible. The `2context.vim` script converts a line to the following

```
\SYNBOL ... \SYNEOL
```

The initial implementation of line numbering was to redefine `\SYNBOL` to add a number in the left margin. This worked but did not provide any of the other options of line numbering environment (set style of number, distance of number, skip, start, conversion, referencing, etc.). I didn't want to reimplement all those features in `t-vim`.
So, I eventually settled for piggy-packing on the built-in line numbering environment, which currently doesn't have the option to specify that some content which belongs to the same line is actually split into two lines.

I don't plan to rewrite the way line numbering is handled in `t-vim`. I'll check on the context mailing list if it is possible to add support for "skip linenumber if on sameline". The code for that is already there in `page-lin.lua` (line 415-422) but is commented out for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Let's hope that it will be uncommented soon :)